# Automation Framework - how to generate simple table form html reports using TestNG with selenium java automation tests

Tags: java, xslt, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have been using Selenium WebDriver with TestNG for doing web application functional testing since last 6 months. I have also used Apache Ant, Apache Maven and Apache POI Library for Project build and data driven testing with MS Excel.

TestNG gives me good flexibility in ordering the tests and executing them. With the help of Listeners and reporters I am able to log and record the test events and results also.

But the HTML reports generated with TestNG are not user friendly. I have also generated XSLT reports using ReportNG dependency in ANT and Maven but these reports are also not formatted well enough to be user friendly.

I have recently started working on selenium automation project for an MNC organization and my manager requires me to have a better framework for automation. The current TestNG and XSLT reports are not ok for corporate use.

Please suggest any test automation framework that works with selenium and preferably TestNG and generates simple user friendly HTML reports in Table format mentioning the number of tests passed, failed, skipped etc. with test names, description etc.

Comment: Hmm. You could check out ExtentReports. Works fine with Selenium and Testng. Here's an example how the report will look like - http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports/Extent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would also recommend ExtentReports - extremely simple to use and generates great info with very little data. Although you can use version 2.02 which is superb sample: http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports2/Extent.html

The guy behind it has also shown how to use with listener here: http://relevantcodes.com/testng-listener-using-extentreports/

Comment: Hi Karthik. Thanks for this idea. I have started to use ExtentReports, these are quite descriptive and interface is also good.

Comment: Thanks Karthik. I am only having one issue. I am using it to generate reports using extent as a listener class which executes and catches results after tests complete. I want to display the unique ID of the test as String in the report. I can capture  this ID field in a variable during test run but variable become null after tests complete and listener class prints null value. how to pass as string an ID value to extent reports listener.

Comment: Also using extent reports along with code in test class seems incorrect way as I have to set the test status as pass or failed using `test.log(Logstatus.PASS or Logstatus.FAIL, "details")` before doing `extent.endtest(test)`. How do I pass and display a string value from test to the  listener based implementation of extentreports?

Comment: Deepak how are you sending unique string which becomes null? Listener will automatically runa at the end. It will create report will all status.. No manual steps. You can also post your queries on relevant codes you may get more accurate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using CI server like Jenkins or Bamboo. It should make a build, run all the tests, aggregate test results and generate the reports from TestNG xml output for every build. Reports will be available boa web interface. Later on, you may like to configure various code analysts tools like FindBugs and automate releasing and deployments via CI server.
You'll not need any other test framework, TestNG and Selenium is enough.

Answer (score 1):

[Allure](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG) Reporting Framework has got testng adapters. You can check it out